# Can I allocate IPv6 addresses to directories of my web server?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ip, ipv6

I am running an apache server on a Debian machine and I have 1 IPv4 addresses and 20 IPv6 addresses. I want to run two websites of this server, can I allocate a directory an IPv6 address so that I can redirect my domain name to that IPv6 or if not, can I run two web servers and have one of them use an IPv6?

Comment: Related: [How to set apache virtualhost to work with ipv6?](http://serverfault.com/questions/332409/how-to-set-apache-virtualhost-to-work-with-ipv6) on Server Fault, and [htaccess mod_rewrite allow ipv6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969376/htaccess-mod-rewrite-allow-ipv6) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) at digitalocean.com which allowed me to specify which folder is for what domain or what IP.